# Уведомления на заблокированном экране. Переход по уведомлению

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Как заставить уведомление быть кликабельным на заблокированном экране?

Код создания уведомления:

```
private void createNotification(String msg, String url) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Текст")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setTicker("Текст")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(alarmSound);

    Intent contentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, contentIntent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, m

    Builder.build());

}
```

Код создает уведомление при переходе по которому открывается страница по ссылке в браузере.

Код работает. Но если экран заблокирован, не срабатывает переход ни одинарным, ни двойным тапом.

*Пример уведомления:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Например, в таких приложениях как Viber, VKontakte, GMail переход по уведомлению с заблокированного экрана работает.

Comment: Врятли у вас получится сделать это для всех видов блокировки и на всех устройствах. Например у меня что-то типа графического ключа для разблокировки и ВК-шное уведомление не открывает приложение пока я экран не разблокирую. При нажатии появляется надпись "разблокируйте" и только после этого приложение запускается.

Comment: Но ведь это возможно при разблокировке свайпом по экрану?

Comment: Тут не скажу - не пробовал.